# AngularJS calling a controller from a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

I have a model called 'user', 'user' has a controller called 'login' and a directive called 'userMenu', what I'm trying to achieve is that the userMenu directive uses the controller 'login' that's available in the module. Maybe I don't understand well how the modules and directives should work but I'm doing the following:

First, I define my controller like this:

```
angular.module('user', []).
controller('login', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.logIn = function(){
        //Do something...
    }
}
```

Then, in my directive...

```
angular.module('user', []).
directive('userMenu', function(){
    return {
    priority: 0,
    templateUrl: 'app/includes/user/menu.html',
    replace: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: 'login',
    }
});
```

But the I get this:

```
Error: Argument 'login' is not a function, got undefined
```

Would you please guide me on the use of directives and controllers within modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-defining the `user` directive while preparing your directive. I presume that you wanted to register both a controller and a directive on the same module. If so you can register your directive like this:

```
angular.module('user').directive('userMenu', function(){
    return {
    ...
    }
});
```

Notice that there is no second argument ([]) to the call of `angular.module` which means that you want to retrieve an instance of already defined module instead of defining a new one.

Comment: you were absolutely right, thanks! I didn't know that it was defining the module again :D